# Duplicate classes in identical packages, but only one of those can be imported

Tags: java, eclipse, project-structure, buildpath

I am working on a legacy Java app and am investigating why there are duplicate classes in 2 of the projects, used in the workspace.

So the classes from **project1** and **project2** are both in `com.example.SomeClass` - the package name is the same, as well as the class name.
That is all that is contained in the import statement, I cannot state from which package I want to import it.
However, in the Java Build Path tab in Eclipse I can see that both **project1** and **project2** are added.

So how does it decide if it will import `project1.com.example.SomeClass`, or from p`roject2.com.example.SomeClass`?

Comment: It decides by the order: _Project > Properties: Java Build Path_ tab _Order and Export_.

Answer (score 0):

Class precedence for different classes sharing the same package and name relies on the default **ClassLoader** (unless you set a different **ClassLoader**). This is implementation-specific (it depends if you're using e.g. **OpenJDK**, **Oracle JDK** ...etc).

Usually you'd expect that it would use the precedence defined at the classpath, but this is not mandatory.